# Decoding mp4/h264 video frames on the JVM

Tags: video, java

I need to process some mp4 videos on the JVM, so I understand I need something that calls into **OpenMAX** for **performance reasons**. I read somewhere that the [JogAmp](http://jogamp.org/) or perhaps the JOGL sub-project provide such bindings.

I found some references on the Internet that suggested that there by something like a 'GLMediaPlayer' and a demo 'MovieCube' showcasing this, but I cannot locate any further information or source code. There is some broken applet without references to source code:

https://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/jogl-applet-runner-newt-MovieCube-applet3-napplet.html

So the question is: How do I efficiently decode the frames of an mp4/h264 video on the JVM **on the Raspberry Pi** with performance ok for the **Raspberry Pi**? I know omxplayer, but I need to do further processing such as triggering specific sequences in time, applying fade-in/fade-out etc. So I need an API I can call from Java or Scala.

Comment: You make it sound a little unrelated to the Raspberry Pi which would render the question off-topic here.

Comment: @Ghanima JogAmp is specifically built for cross-platform playback, _including Raspberry Pi with OpenMAX (= Raspberry Pi HARDWARE ACCEL)_ support

Comment: I don't mind leaving this here, but "cross-platform" would make it not [*specific to* the Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), meaning you would probably be better off asking on S.O.  But you seem to have enough of an account to know that already...you may get an answer, just don't hold your breath.  We don't have a huge gaggle of java users (note, ~150 tagged questions in 4+ years).

Comment: Put another way, the fact that you haven't found a pi-specific java lib for this probably means there isn't one, or at least, isn't one worth fooling with, so you want something generic that will make use of the native openMAX interface, which should exploit the hardware.  Of course, if you do get it figured out, please leave an answer ;)

Comment: @goldilocks Yeah, it's a bit sad Raspi folks seem all over Python. I really don't like that language and pushing more for JVM coverage.

Comment: I'm not a python fanatic either; I like java, but I like C++ more and that's what I mostly use on the Pi (if you can do anything in any language, somewhere down there C is involved, at least on GNU/Linux, so you can do whatever in C, and by extension, C++).  Anyway, if you have any C at all, maybe now is the time to learn some **JNI**.  The main reason I've never gotten into python is perl was a first language for me; when I learned how to use XS (akin to JNI -- you're interfacing perl with C) it opened up the whole world.  Chocolate and peanut butter.